# How could I use Bash to find 2 bytes in a binary file, increase their values, and replace?

Tags: text-processing, conversion, replace, binary

I'm trying to find two bytes inside binary file, then increase value of those two bytes and replace them inside file. Those two bytes are on positions 0x82-0x83. For now on I have successfully extracted those two bytes using this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
BYTES=$(tail -c +131 "$1" | head -c 2)
```

Those bytes have value: `1B 1F`. I'm stuck with:

1. How to convert bytes to integer? It should be `6943` decimal.
2. How to append / echo  binary data to file
3. How to write increased bytes inside file on positions 0x82-0x83. I could use `head -c 130 original.bin >> new_file.bin && magic_command_writing_bytes_to_file >> new_file.bin && tail -c +133 original.bin`, but there must be better way.

I could do that in PHP, it should be easier, but I'm interested how to do this in bash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Testing with this file:

```
$ echo hello world > test.txt
$ echo -n $'\x1b\x1f' >> test.txt
$ echo whatever >> test.txt
$ hexdump -C test.txt 
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f  72 6c 64 0a 1b 1f 77 68  |hello world...wh|
00000010  61 74 65 76 65 72 0a                              |atever.|
$ grep -a -b --only-matching $'\x1b\x1f' test.txt 
12:
```

So in this case the `1B 1F` is at position `12`.

- Convert to integer (there is probably an easier way)

  ```
  $ echo 'ibase=16; '`xxd -u -ps -l 2 -s 12 test.txt`  | bc
  6943
  ```
- And the reverse:

  ```
  $ printf '%04X' 6943 | xxd -r -ps | hexdump -C
  00000000  1b 1f                                             |..|
  $ printf '%04X' 4242 | xxd -r -ps | hexdump -C
  00000000  10 92                                             |..|
  ```
- And putting it back in the file:

  ```
  $ printf '%04X' 4242 | xxd -r -ps | dd of=test.txt bs=1 count=2 seek=12 conv=notrunc
  2+0 records in
  2+0 records out
  2 bytes (2 B) copied, 5.0241e-05 s, 39.8 kB/s
  ```
- Result:

  ```
  $ hexdump -C test.txt
  00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f  72 6c 64 0a 10 92 77 68  |hello world...wh|
  00000010  61 74 65 76 65 72 0a                              |atever.|
  ```

Comment: Yes, It's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @frostschutz: There is a bug —a missing `\x`— in line two of your example code. It should be `echo -n $'\x1b\x1f' >> test.txt`.

Comment: *Convert to integer (there is probably an easier way)* Oh yes, there is! :) erik chose the best command, so I'll just adapt his  line to yours: `printf "%d" 0x1B1F` will do the job just fine to obtain your `6943` result; going from that, you can use a significantly smarter line like `printf "%d" $(xxd -u -ps -l 2 -s 12 test.txt)` instead and you won't be needing `bc` any longer.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, sorry. This answer is obsolete, because I thought you have hexadecimal values written as ascii in your file.

---

You can convert the hex numbers to decimal system via `printf "%d" 0x1B1F`.

If you have saved the bytes in a variable `BYTES=1B1F` then you get the result with `printf "%d" 0x$BYTES`.

So, if you want to increase the number do

```
$ echo $(($(printf "%d" 0x$BYTES) +1))
6944
```

Then convert it back

```
printf '%X' $(($(printf "%d" 0x$BYTES) +1))
1B20
```