# Why is od calculating decimal values wrong?

Tags: od, hex, byte

This question is related to the answer from enzotib to the question: [How could I use Bash to find 2 bytes in a binary file, increase their values, and replace?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88848/how-could-i-use-bash-to-find-2-bytes-in-a-binary-file-increase-their-values-an)

This converts the two bytes into its hex value:

```
$ echo -n $'\x1b\x1f' | od -tx2
0000000 1f1b
0000002
```

But now, this should give me the decimal value:

```
echo -n $'\x1b\x1f' | od -tu2
0000000  7963
0000002
```

But if I convert the hex value into decimal it should be

```
$ printf "%d" 0x1b1f
6943
```

Why is that? Am I using `od` wrong for decimal output?

Answer (score 4):

You're running `od` on a [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) machine.

```
>>> 0x1f1b
7963
```